# How to deal with an HDF5 file that cannot be open

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am using the Python h5py library and I am not a C/C++ programmer.

I have a file that has been made unreadable because a long write operation to create a dataset was interrupted.

If it's possible, I would like to be able to open the file and delete the damaged dataset so that I could reload it without losing all the other data.

I tried to open the file in the following HDF5 utilities with the given error messages.

- h5dump:  `h5dump error: unable to open file "test.h5"`
- HDFView: `Error opening file test.h5`
- HDFCompass:

```
INFO    pydap.request:39 > Opening file:///C:\Users\HIAPRC\Documents\CH149\One_off_code\hdf5_check\test.h5.dds
DEBUG   hdf_compass.opendap_model.model.can_handle:61 > able to handle file:///C:\Users\HIAPRC\Documents\CH149\One_off_code\hdf5_check\test.h5? no
DEBUG   hdf_compass.asc_model.model.can_handle:74 > able to handle file:///C:\Users\HIAPRC\Documents\CH149\One_off_code\hdf5_check\test.h5? no, missing .asc extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\john\hdf-compass\hdf_compass\compass_viewer\frame.py", line 199, in on_file_open
  File "c:\users\john\hdf-compass\hdf_compass\compass_viewer\frame.py", line 223, in open_url
  File "c:\users\john\hdf-compass\hdf_compass\compass_viewer\viewer.py", line 175, in can_open_store
  File "c:\users\john\hdf-compass\hdf_compass\bag_model\model.py", line 88, in can_handle
  File "site-packages\hydroffice\bag\base.py", line 31, in is_bag
  File "site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 272, in __init__
  File "site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 92, in make_fid
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2587)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2546)
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 76, in h5py.h5f.open (C:\aroot\work\h5py\h5f.c:1821)
IOError: Unable to open file (Bad object header version number)
```

Any clues as to how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about `h5debug`?  Or look for other `h5` rescue scripts.

Comment: @hpaulj. I tried h5debug and it "cannot open file". I tried h5dump and it was a non-starter as well. I'll google around for rescue scripts. Thanks. Do you happen to know of an article or paper which discusses how one should manage large amounts of data? Right now we have a file that is over 600GB and I am worried that one day we won't be able to open or recover.

Comment: @PlacidLush, you could save different datasets in separate files and use external links to reference them from a single file.

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks for the tip. I have done some testing and I like what I see so far.